# Why is my income tax and poll tax zero?

Tags: victoria-3

Having played the newly released Victoria 3 for a few hours now, I came across an odd scenario where some of the tax incomes are showing up as zeros.

I have the tax policy set to per capita and the population of the nation is in the millions, however, I did notice that a large portion of the populate is considered "dependent" but still that should bring in some tax revenue.

Has anyone come across the same issue?

Comment: I found a Reddit saying something about event modifiers, but I don't know the game so I don't know if this could be it or not: https://www.reddit.com/r/victoria3/comments/yfkffl/income_tax_bug_from_an_event/